# Why I'm I getting "inf" for my weighted potential

Tags: awk, histogram, block

I am making use of awk script to create a histogram from my data:

## My file looks like this:

```
#! FIELDS time p1.sss p1.zzz bias
0.000000 1.717539 0.694226 0.600000
0.020000 1.716644 0.696346 0.0000300
0.040000 1.715884 0.691981 3.861161
0.060000 1.715452 0.703569 0.000000
0.080000 1.715754 0.697158 0.020000
0.100000 1.716890 0.690405 2.050000
0.120000 1.718104 0.700375 0.070000
0.140000 1.719044 0.710520 5.000000
0.160000 1.719809 0.712205 0.000000
0.180000 1.720627 0.729156 0.090000
```

## The awk script that I used is:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    grep -v \# datas | tail -n 100 |
    awk 'BEGIN{
    min1=-3.14159265358979
    max1=+3.14159265358979
    min2=-3.14159265358979
    max2=+3.14159265358979
    nb1=4;
    nb2=4;
    for(i1=0;i1<nb1;i1++) for(i2=0;i2<nb2;i2++) f[i1,i2]=0.0;
    }{
    i1=int(($2-min1)*nb1/(max1-min1));
    i2=int(($3-min2)*nb2/(max2-min2));
    # we assume the potential is in the last column, and kbT=2.5 kj/mol
    w=exp($4/2.5);
    f[i1,i2]+=w;
    }END{
    for(i1=0;i1<nb1;i1++){
    for(i2=0;i2<nb2;i2++) print min1+i1/100.0*(max1-min1), min2+i2/100.0*(max2-min2), -2.5*log(f[i1,i2]);
    print "";
    }}' > plotme
```

When I ran this awk script, the values are in blocks as expected but I got "inf" output for almost all the function in column 3 as:

```
-3.14159 -3.14159 inf
-3.14159 -3.07876 inf
-3.14159 -3.01593 inf
-3.14159 -2.9531 inf

-3.07876 -3.14159 inf
-3.07876 -3.07876 inf
-3.07876 -3.01593 inf
-3.07876 -2.9531 inf

-3.01593 -3.14159 inf
-3.01593 -3.07876 inf
-3.01593 -3.01593 inf
-3.01593 -2.9531 inf

-2.9531 -3.14159 inf
-2.9531 -3.07876 inf
-2.9531 -3.01593 -7.69205
-2.9531 -2.9531 inf
```

Please, kindly help me to find what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Come on, indent your code at least. Show a BIT of effort.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the `inf`s are coming from the expression `-2.5*log(f[i1,i2])`, so it's clear that some values of the matrix are 0, and thus it's likely that some entries in the matrix are not updated in the way you evidently expect. Have you tried adding "print" statements to assist with debugging?  Here's one to consider:  `print "f["i1","i2"] = " f[i1,i2];`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Morton. When I try to the print "f["i1","i2"] = " f[i1,i2]; , I got no result for my function, the output looks like f[2,4] =; this is a clear indication that f[i1,i2] was not updated at all. What could be the problem

Comment: You assume `i1` and `i2` are between 0 and 4, but there is no guarantee that they would be since you update with your data

Comment: I do not have problem with the values of i1 and i2 but my problem is with the function f[i1,i2] that keeps given me zero values as what it was set to at the command line `for(i1=0;i1<nb1;i1++) for(i2=0;i2<nb2;i2++) f[i1,i2]=0.0;` instead of its update at the command line `f[i1,i2]+=w;`

Comment: Please print the values i1 and i2 in your loop and see what range of values it gets.  You don't compute f for all values i1,i2 in your loop counter.  You will see that only 2,2 and 2,3 values are computed.

Comment: @karakfa The array of i1 and i2 is fine. I got the expected array like 

0 0\
0 1\
0 2\
0 3\
space
1 0\
1 1\
1 2\
1 3\
space
2 0\
2 1\
2 2\
2 3\
space
3 0\
3 1\
3 2\
3 3\

Comment: I'm not sure, I think you print your for loop.  I mean the main `awk` statement, i.e. add print after these `w=exp($4/2.5);  f[i1,i2]+=w;`  as `print i1,i2,w`

Comment: @karakfa That is true, i can see that i only got 3 and 2 for i1 and i2. What could be the problem

Comment: why do you assume `i1=int(($2-min1)*nb1/(max1-min1));` will span the full range?

Comment: @karakfa Thanks for your efforts, I had no idea of spanning the full range, I was only trying to apply the script as I found it applied somewhere else. My interest is splitting the values into bins which can then be plotted with contour plot. I want to count the probability of an the values to be in a precise bin. Is there any other way to this?

Comment: your data is heavily clustered around these values, won't give you enough range.  perhaps you can extend your data samples?  Also, try printing the computed values of i1 and i2 before you convert to int to verify, perhaps scaling will help (but not with this sample).  Good luck.

Comment: @karakfa Thanks for all your supports and suggestions. I got it right. I just set the min and max to the minimum and maximum of the corresponding data they represent and the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

The range of the values you are not from 0 to 4.  For your double iteration most f values end up empty.  Here is quick rewrite of your function based on your data only a few index values are computed.

$ cat test.awk

```
    BEGIN {
            PI = 2*atan2(1,0)
            min1 = min2 = -PI
            max1 = max2 = PI
            nb1 = nb2 = 4
    }

    {
            i1 = int(($2 - min1) * nb1 / (max1 - min1))
            i2 = int(($3 - min2) * nb2 / (max2 - min2))
            w = exp($4 / 2.5)
            f[i1","i2] += w
    }

    END {
           for (k in f) {
               split(k,i,",");
               print k":" min1 + i[1]/100*(max1 - min1),
                          min2 + i[2]/100*(max2 - min2), 
                          -2.5 * log(f[k])
           }
    }
```

The key point is in your end block you have to make sure you iterating over the indices only in your `f` array.

Running gives this

```
$ awk -f test.awk data

2,2:-3.01593 -3.01593 0
3,2:-2.9531 -3.01593 -7.69205
```

so, only 2,2 and 3,2 indices are computed.

You initialize f array with zeros and the values stays zero for most indices. 
Try this, perhaps will help you understand the reason why you get Inf.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print log(0)}'
```